# SVG + Inkscape - добавить радиусы на углах прямоугольников

Tags: css, svg, inkscape

```html
<svg width="99"  height="99" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
    <path
       id="rect135"
       d="M 17.097472,5.7761733 H 30.190131 V 14.17088 H 17.097472 Z"
       fill="#ff0000"
       style="stroke-width:0.704923" />
</svg>
```

Есть данная фигура, как мне добавить радиус к углам, к красной фигуре через Inkscape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- #1. Сохраняете в файл с расширением ***.svg**

`fill="none" stroke="black"`  Чтобы был только бордер и не мешала закраска.

```html
<svg width="99"  height="99" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
    <path
       id="rect135"
       d="M 17.097472,5.7761733 H 30.190131 V 14.17088 H 17.097472 Z"
       fill="none" stroke="black" />
</svg>
```

- #2. В векторном редакторе добавляете направляющие

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- #3. На пересечении направляющих в каждом углу добавляете два дополнительных узла

Для этого нужно дважды щёлкнуть по месту

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- #4. Удаляете  узлы в углах фигуры

См. рисунок ниже.

1. Удаляете узлы
2. Преобразовываете оставшиеся два узла в автоматически сглаженные и рычагами управления добиваетесь нужной формы. Их нужно просто совместить с направляющими

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- #4. Повторяете действия для остальных узлов и сохраняете снова файл ***.svg**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- #5. При необходимости оптимизируете файл с помощью [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

Готовая фигура SVG

```css
.container {
width:100vw;
height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  viewBox="0 0 36 36" version="1.1" id="svg3" >
  <path id="rect135" d="M18.5 5.8h10.2c.7 0 1.5.8 1.5 1.5v5.4c0 .7-.9 1.5-1.6 1.5h-10c-.7 0-1.5-.8-1.5-1.4V7.3c0-.7.7-1.5 1.4-1.5z" fill="gold"   />
</svg>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

Такая техника рисования в векторном редакторе оправдана, когда нужно нарисовать фигуру со сложными контурами, но когда нужно закруглить простые фигуры, то проще сделать это с CSS

Ниже тот же прямоугольник, где углы закругляются с помощью `border-radius`

```css
.rect {
width:198px;
height:99px;
background-color:red;
border-radius:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rect"></div>
```